# How to format a large text field in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have one column named description of mysql text data type. So when retrive the value from this column I need to show it in diffrent text columns. how to divide this single large text into text columns. any one have idea how to do this.

Comment: have you tried anything ? if so please update. also include on what basis you would parse.

Comment: give an example ...and tell us what u tried?and what error you got?

Answer (score 1):

use the word wrap function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

example `wordwrap($str, 80);`

for a new line separator every 80 chars, and not splitting words

Answer (score 0):

Try using a delimiter, example " : ", this makes formats it to be used as a serialized string, when you retrieve it from the database just explode by this delimiter